# In LabVIEW, get callees without loading a VI

Tags: labview

Here's an obscure Friday Morning question:

Is it possible in LabVIEW to get the callees of a VI without loading the entire VI into memory?  For instance, by reading static information from the binary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is the private/scriptig method App.*Read Linker Info From File*, I don't think this will load the VI into memory, for more info have a look at the [LabVIEW wiki](http://labviewwiki.org/Linker.Read_info_from_file) (<del>currently off-line</del> , here is a [Google cached page](http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:IMolDWlaoUcJ:wiki.lavag.org/Linker.Read_info_from_file+labview+read+linker&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl&client=firefox-a)) page on the linker method.

The linker method will return all the info on the VI and it's external needs (VIs, DLLs, CHMs etc).

Ton

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe so. When you open a reference to the top-level VI, it will be loaded into memory. That's even before you have the opportunity to query it for its callees.

Answer (score 0):

Ton's answer is correct. The mentioned method is an application instance method not a VI reference method. You supply the path to the VI in question to that method and it will then parse the VI structure and extract all the relevant linker information without loading the VI as such into memory (Obviously it will read in the information from the file into memory to parse it but it will not load/instantiate the VI itself).

The problem with that node is however that it is private, because it has changed its interface in the past and may do so in the future again without warning. There even was a case between 7.0 and 7.1 or so, where the interface changed without any warning in the form of a broken arrow, but when executing it with the old data structure it would simply crash. As a private node that is fully valid, as no warranties are made about the functionality of private nodes.